# $\int \frac{dx}{x^2 \sqrt{x^{2}-4)}}, x=2\sec(t) $ Am I eliminating the absolute value correctly?

Tags: integration

$$ \int \frac{dx}{x^2 \sqrt{(x^{2}-4)}},\quad x=2\sec(t).$$
After substitution

$$\int \frac{2\tan(t)\sec(t)}{(2\sec(t))^{2}\sqrt{(2sec(t))^2-4}}=\frac{1}{4}\int \frac{\cos(t)\tan(t)}{\sqrt{\tan^{2}(t)}}.$$
and for $g(t)=2\sec(t), t \in (0,\pi)$ such that $g:(0,\pi)\rightarrow (-\infty,-2)\cup(2,\infty) $
$$\frac{\tan(t)}{|\tan(t)|}=\frac{|\cos(t)|}{\cos(t)}$$
then
$$ \frac{1}{4} \int_{}^{} |\cos(t)| dt$$
and
$$ \frac{1}{4} \int_{}^{} \cos(t) dt = \frac{1}{4} \sin(t), t \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$$
$$ \frac{1}{4} \int_{}^{} -\cos(t) dt = -\frac{1}{4} \sin(t), t \in (\frac{\pi}{2},\pi)$$

$sin(t)=\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-4}}{x}$ but $sin(t)\geq 0, \forall t \in (0,\pi)$ then $sin(t)=\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-4}}{|x|},  \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

finally

$$ \frac{1}{4} \int_{}^{} \cos(t) dt = \frac{1}{4} \frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-4}}{x} + C, t \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2}), x\geq0$$
$$ \frac{1}{4} \int_{}^{} -\cos(t) dt = -\frac{1}{4} \frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-4}}{-x}=\frac{1}{4} \frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-4}}{x} + C, t \in (\frac{\pi}{2},\pi), x<0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final answer looks correct, just a few remarks.

You are missing the constant of integration. Since $\tan(t)$ is not defined at $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$, this needs to be excluded in the interval. Note also that $\sqrt{x^2-4}\geq 0$ for $x\leq -2$ and $x\geq 2$.

For the $\textbf{indefinite}$ integral we write

$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-4}}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{4x}+C$$

since we are not given the limits of integration. When we are given the limits, we split the integration intervals according to the absolute value.